# Using a command in my batch file without the needed xml

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, outlook

I have to uninstall Office 2013 on some Clients at our company and needed a short script to do it so it runs autonom.

```
@echo off
echo Start Uninstall Programm
echo Removing Office 2013...

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall Proplus /config "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\PROPLUS\uninstallOffice.xml"

echo Uninstall complete, pls reboot now.
```

The Programm is working perfect but for the Office uninstall it needs a .xml file that holds some informations:

```
<Configuration Product="ProPlus">

<Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />

</Configuration>
```

But now i have to let the Prorgramm run on a client without the .xml file and there is no way for me to copy it there.
Is there a way to let the batch file know what it has to know from the .xml file without actually having a .xml file?
Or is there a way to let the batch file write an .xml file, save it, and use it afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to embed the xml into batch:

```
<!-- : batch
@echo off
echo Start Uninstall Programm
echo Removing Office 2013...

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall Proplus /config "%~f0"

echo Uninstall complete, pls reboot now.
exit /b %errorlevel%

 --->


<Configuration Product="ProPlus">

<Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />

</Configuration>
```

Save this as `.bat` and try it .If the setup.exe is not sensitive about the file extensions it could work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the setup.exe needs the file extension.
Will test it later to make sure.
Also i dont 100% understand how the setup.exe knows that it should use the embedded xml, would be nice if u could explain it

Comment: @Paxz - the part between `<!--` and `-->` will be a comment for the xml. For cmd exe the line `<!-- : batch` will be parsed as `:<!--  batch` (the batch files have parse and execution phases) which during the execution will be taken as a label i.e. ignored.So this allows you to execute batch code in xml comment block.And everything after the `exit` line will be ignored by cmd.exe.

Comment: Seems I fogot to mark this as correct a while ago, well better late than never I guess :D